# how to stop multithread chat client

Tags: java, multithreading, client, chat

I'm trying to create a multithread chat client-server using Java. I'm using this tutorial as a start: http://pguides.net/java-tutorial/java-tcp-clientserver-chat/

I want the client to stop when I enter the String "quit" but I don't understand how I could do it. Also, I need to remove the client from the connected nicks list when the client disconnects.

Server

```
/* ChatServer.java */
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class ChatServer {
    private static int port = 1001; 

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket client = null;
        while(true) {
            try {
                client = server.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Accept failed.");
                System.err.println(e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            /* start a new thread to handle this client */
            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientConn(client));
            t.start();
        }
       }
}

class ChatServerProtocol {
    private String nick;
    private ClientConn conn;

    private static Hashtable<String, ClientConn> nicks = new Hashtable<String, ClientConn>();

    private static final String msg_OK = "OK";
    private static final String msg_INVALID = "INVALID COMMAND";
    private static final String msg_SEND_FAILED = "FAILED TO SEND";

    private static boolean add_nick(String nick, ClientConn c) {
        if (nicks.containsKey(nick)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            nicks.put(nick, c);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static boolean remove_nick(String nick, ClientConn c) {
        if (!(nicks.containsKey(nick))) {
            return false;
        } else {
            nicks.remove(nick);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ChatServerProtocol(ClientConn c) throws IOException {
        nick = null;
        conn = c;
    }


    private boolean sendMsg(String recipient, String msg) {
        if (nicks.containsKey(recipient)) {
            ClientConn c = nicks.get(recipient);
            c.sendMsg(nick + ": " + msg);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public String process(String msg) {
        if (msg.startswith("Nick"){
        String output = "";
        if(add_nick(tryauthor, this.conn)) {
            this.nick = tryauthor;
            output = "Welcome "+tryauthor;
            } else {
                    output = "Nick already in";
                }
            }

        }
        else if (msg.startsWith("msg")) {
            String[] msg_parts = msg.split(":");
            for(int i=0; i<msg_parts.length; i++){
                System.out.println(msg_parts[i]);
            }
            String msg_type = msg_parts[0];
            if(msg_type.equals("msg")) {
                if(msg_parts.length < 3) output = msg_INVALID;
                if(sendMsg(msg_parts[1], msg_parts[2])) output = msg_OK;
                else output = msg_SEND_FAILED;
            } else {
                output = msg_INVALID;
            }
        }

        return output;
     }
    }

class ClientConn implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;
    private BufferedReader in = null;
    private PrintWriter out = null;

    public ClientConn(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
        try {
            /* obtain an input stream to this client ... */
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            /* ... and an output stream to the same client */
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        String msg, response;

        try {
             ChatServerProtocol protocol = new ChatServerProtocol(this);
            /* loop reading lines from the client which are processed 
             * according to our protocol and the resulting response is 
             * sent back to the client */
            while ((msg = in.readLine()) != "quit\r\n") {
                response = protocol.process(msg);
                out.println("SERVER: " + response);
            }
            this.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void sendMsg(String msg) {
        out.println(msg);
     }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        client.close();
    }

}
```

Client

```
/* ChatClient.java */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ChatClient {
private static int port = 1001; 
private static String host = "localhost"; 

private static BufferedReader stdIn;

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket server = null;

    try {
        server = new Socket(host, port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));

    System.out.print("Nick: ");
    String auth = stdIn.readLine();
    out.println("Nick: " + auth);
    String serverResponse = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(serverResponse);

    if (serverResponse.startsWith("SERVER: welcome")) {
         /* create a thread to asyncronously read messages from the server */
        ServerConn sc = new ServerConn(server);
        Thread t = new Thread(sc);
        t.start();

        String msg;
        /* loop reading messages from stdin and sending them to the server */
        while ((msg = stdIn.readLine()) != "quit\r\n") {
            out.println(msg);
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("Exit.");
        System.out.println("---Client Error---");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Exit.");
        System.out.println("---Client Error---");
    }


  }
}

class ServerConn implements Runnable {
    private BufferedReader in = null;
    private Socket server;

    public ServerConn(Socket s) throws IOException {
        server = s;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void run() {
        String msg;
        try {
            /* loop reading messages from the server and show them 
             * on stdout */
             while ((msg = in.readLine()) != "quit\r\n") {
                System.out.println(msg);
             }
             this.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
      }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        server.close();
    }

}
```

Where and how should I close the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now the client can be authenticated only if his name is part of a graph I've created before.

This seems to be written in the code.  In your `Process()` method, you look for the author in the `authorsgraph` and if it is not found you return an error.  Is this not what you intended?    If the author is not found, should you add them instead?  Maybe the `add_nice()` call should be in the `else` if you haven't found them along with some way to add the author to the `authorsgraph`?

Walking through the handling of a new connection in a debugger might help you here.  Liberal use of `System.out.println()` messages might also be of service.

> I want the client to stop when I enter the String "quit" but I don't understand how I could do it.

Well this code has a bug.  You must use `.equals()` to check for `String` equality.  `!=` is only testing the `msg` doesn't have the same `String` *reference*, not the same string *contents*:

```
// can't use != on a `String` to check contents
while ((msg = stdIn.readLine()) != "quit\r\n") {
```

It should be:

```
while (true) {
   msg = stdIn.readLine();
   if (msg == null || msg.equals("quit")) {
      break;
   }
   ...
```

Notice also that I am not checking the "\r\n".  The `readLine()` method returns the string (to quote from the javadocs) "not including any line-termination characters".  Also, you should test against `null` in case the socket is closed.  You also have 2 places in your client code with the same bug.

> I need to remove the client from the connected nicks list when the client disconnects.

Your `while` loop above will exit if the client socket is closed or they enter `"quit"`.  You then call `close()`.  After you call `close()` you could call `protocol.remove_nicks()` to remove him from the loop.  But you don't have the `"nick"` `String` there.

Really, maintaining the list of `nicks`  inside of the `ChatServerProtocol` may not be the right place for it.  I would roll the `ChatServerProtocol` into the `ClientConn` class myself since there is one of each per connection.  Either way some object needs to store the `"nick"` string that the author logged in with and then call `remove_nick()` with that string after `"quit"` is entered or the connection closes.

Lastly, use of `HashTable` has been deprecated since Java 5.  I would use `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<...>())` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the authentication part is already working for me, if the author is not part of the graph the client is stopped as it should be. I've tried modifying the code as you suggested but it still doesn't work, after I log in as an author, if I enter quit the client doesn't stop.

Comment: I loaded your code.  You have 2 places in your client code that you have the == "quit" bug that you need to fix.  In the client you should call `server.close()` not `close()` on your `SocketConn` when quitting.  This will close the socket, and the thread will get a closed exception that you should catch and ignore.  To fix the `remove_nick()` issue, I just removed the `static` and `nick` argument so it could use the `nick` field.  Here's my client (http://pastebin.com/KqYvrim2) and server (http://pastebin.com/7GDsYh9G) that works.  I had to remove your graph stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the client to stop when I enter the String "quit" but I don't understand how I could do it.

You can terminate the current Java programm immediately with `System.exit(status)`. As the operating system automatically releases all resources (such as tcp sockets) acquired by a process when it terminates, that also closes your connection.

> Also, I need to remove the client from the connected nicks list when the client disconnects.

That's harder. Keep in mind that a disconnect can happen for reasons other than the client terminating, for instance because the network cable is unplugged. That is, the client can not reliably inform the server that it is no longer there, the server must detect this itself. I would expect the tcp implementation of the server operating system to detect that the client is no longer there (how quickly is probably implementation dependent), and throw an exception to the application using that socket, which you can catch and remove the nick from the list.